# Rails 3.1beta Sprockets finds image but image is not displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I am not sure the best way to explain this one, I have installed Rails 3.1beta with Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows 7, created a new app with these routes:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'admin' do

scope :module => "admin" do

  #resources :undo_items do
    #post 'undo', :on => :member
  #end

  #resources :projects, :domains, :emails, :databases, :admins, :services do
  resources :projects do
  end

  #match "projects" => "projects#index"
  #match "domains" => "domains#index"

  root :to => "projects#index"
end

end

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# just remember to delete public/index.html.
root :to => 'admin/projects#index'
```

One example of the sass is:

```
div {

        h1 { width: 177px; height: 54px; 
             background: url("summit-logo.png") no-repeat;
             float:left; position: relative; top: 15px; 

             a { text-indent: -9999px; display: block; 
                 width: 100%; height: 100%; }

        }
```

When the route is requested:

```
Started GET "/assets/summit-logo.png" FOR 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-23 09:26:12 +0100

[Sprockets] /summit-logo.png 9a3c3...rest of unique request... fresh
```

The image is under app/assets/images/summit-logo.png

Any ideas as to why Sprockets seems to find it but it is not being displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a bug in Sprockes**

The reason for this is that in Windows Sprockets reads the images in text mode which results in all kinds of corruptions. In almost all cases it results in sending less bytes than declared in the `Content-length` header. In Firefox you can actually see that the page is still loading for about 30 seconds. That's the time the browser waits for the missing bytes.

It seems that this will be resolved soon: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1207

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for it under
url(/assets/summit-logo.png)
but I think it's weird, that you do not get a 404.

In my case sprockets (or somebody else down the pipe) somehow re-encodes my images, so they get all distorted. Well, beta troubles...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I may just put this down to the beta as I still can't figure it out, thinking to test in OSX soon to see if I get any better results.